# JQuery range slider (with 2 handlers)

Tags: jquery, slider, range

I'm using JQuery range slider with 2 handlers (price range slider). the problem is, stop event (user slides by clicking on handler and leave) not working in IE7. But it's working fine with IE8 and other browsers. Can anybody give the solution for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: adding some code would help...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using different versions (newer AND older) of jQuery.